# How to check if somebody in Nigeria is in need or a scammer?

Tags: scams, nigeria

My girlfriend has a remote friend in Nigeria with whom she has corresponded from time to time for a couple of years already. He never asked her for money in the past. However, he is now writing to her that the economic situation there is very bad and that he is in hospital with no other relative to help him pay for his fee and food.

1. First of all, how do I check whether he is really in need?
2. And what would be a reasonable sum of help for such a situation there?

Given his location, I'm mostly suspicious but given he is kind of a friend I thought that maybe he deserves a chance. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you *really* think there is a chance this is legitimate?

Comment: Respond "I'm sorry, I can't send you any money", and see if your girlfriend ever hears back from this person.

Comment: Can anybody answer how is it possible to check? As I said they communicated in the past and he asks for money for the first time. If I thought there is no chance, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: For privacy reasons it's almost certainly not possible to verify.

Comment: Definitely a scam

Comment: How did your girlfriend come to know this person "in Nigeria" ?

Comment: @akostadinov A good scammer never asks for money immediately. They build up trust first to lower your guard and then hit you with the money pitch.

Comment: Does Nigeria have a means to independently verify identity or admission to a hospital? It is not proof of his identity nor is it proof of this not being a scam. Details not provided by the scammer to validate they exist as a person can uncover a scam. An additional caveat is that such identity proofing isn't perfect in a first world nation, its even less so in developing nations.

Comment: How do you tell if these two things aren't mutually exclusive. This question is unfortunately off topic and I therefore vote to close. The question isn't about money, it's about judging the intentions of a stranger that you've met on the internet.

Comment: "How to verify if a person in Nigeria is really in need" isn't really a personal finance question.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I was directed here from sceptics. I think it makes some sense because it is about helping me make a decision whether to send money or not.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's equally off topic in both. This is an interpersonal question more than anything else. But I would suggest looking at some of the governmental sites about scams, and remembering that someone you know only on line is not someone you actually know much, if anything, about. (Including us, though at least here we're sanity-checking each other to some degree.) If you aren't certain, don't send. At least don't send more than you would mind losing -- but a standard pattern is for the scammer to start small and keep progressively asking for more once you're hooked.

Comment: Seems unusual to have such a long relationship before money is requested, but still feels very much like a scam. One could ask for a video chat (not to check, just to chat and inquire about their well-being and conditions in hospital), it should be obvious if they are indeed in a hospital. Expect lots of excuses, or the friend being suddenly released from hospital (but still having bills to pay of course). One might also try to contact a local charity or NGO and ask them to visit the friend, but I’m not sure this is going to be easy.

Comment: @jcaron, what you say makes sense and deserves to be an answer. idk why I didn't think about it. Despite it doesn't expand on "local charity or NGO and ask them to visit the friend", which would also be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult to remotely verify if the person is genuine or scam. If you personally know someone you can ask. There are no services that will do this for a fees. In fact a company claiming to do this is more likely a scam.

These are developing countries and even few hundred dollars is lots of money.

Comment: That's a good point. Aren't there some local NPEs or something one can rely on?